# Apple Developer Program enrolment outside of Apple listed regions

Tags: ios, itunes, ios-appstore, developer-program

I’m new to iOS development also and want to enrol in Apple developer program. My question is how can I purchase ADP from Bangladesh?

Anyone purchase ADP by Payoneer master card outside of USA?

Also have Visa Card from Standard Chartered (can't charge in USD).

Some people advice me to get a bank account in other country like UK, USA (don't know how they suggest me to do that while I'm not in that country!). However if I manage to get a physical address and bank account in any of these countries am I able to purchase ADP? What about tax or it is possible literally while you’re not in that country?

Anyone experienced purchasing ADP outside of Apple’s listed regions like Bangladesh?

Really appreciate if you've any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer in South Africa and I don't have a bank in USA.

You enroll with your Apple ID, and the $99 will deduct from the card you have added to it. If you don't have an Apple ID, you can create one and add your card details there.

It doesn't need to be a credit card, you can pay with a debit card as well, as long as it can do online payments (usually cheque accounts). If you don't have a credit card or a cheque card, you can buy a pre-paid MasterCard/VISA card and just recharge it with money *(might have problems with the cardholder name, see below)*. I don't have a credit card but I do have a chipped VISA debit card (from South Africa) which works for online payments and works for Apple Developer Program.

And anyone can register from any country. :)

---

#### What payment methods can I use?

You can pay for your items with a Visa, Mastercard, Discover, or American Express.

#### Can I use a credit card other than my own to complete my purchase?

The payment information you provide must match exactly with your enrollment information. If this information does not match, your enrollment will be delayed and you may be asked to provide a copy of a government issued identification.

Comment: Thanks! So you think Payoneer will work?

Comment: I dont know what that is but if the cardholder name is your name, then yes I would say it will work! :)

Comment: @Asha, care to share your experience about opening the Paid Apple Developer program? Did you succeed with your payment method?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can enroll in ADP from a different country, all you'll have to do is that you'll have to have the ability to pay Apple $99/year.

However, the main issue will be submitting your app in the app store and then getting paid for them.

**[Stripe Atlas](https://stripe.com/atlas)** may be the only reasonable option for that IMHO. I haven't tested it though.